# Etiquette when asking questions in an IRC channel

Tags: open-source, communication

Many larger OSS projects maintain IRC channels to discuss their usage or development. When I get stuck on using a project, having tried and failed to find information on the web, one of the ways I try to figure out what to do is to go into the IRC channel and ask.

But my questions are invariably completely ignored by the people in the channel. If there was silence when I entered, there will still be silence. If there is an ongoing conversation, it carries on unperturbed. I leave the channel open for a few hours, hoping that maybe someone will eventually engage me, but nothing happens.

So I worry that I'm being rude in some way I don't understand, or breaking some unspoken rule and being ignored for it. I try to make my questions polite, to the point, and grammatical, and try to indicate that I've tried the obvious solutions and why they didn't work. I understand that I'm obviously a complete stranger to the people on the channel, but I'm not sure how to fix this. Should I just lurk in the channel, saying nothing, for a week? That seems absurd too.

A typical message I send might be "Hello all - I've been trying to get Foo to work, but I keep on getting a BarException. I tried resetting the Quux, but this doesn't seem to do anything. Does anyone have a suggestion on what I could try?"

Comment: It depends on the channel. No two are alike... Best thing to do is to lurk for a while before posting - see how things are done and then join in in the expected manner.

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with programming?

Comment: @JoelEtherton: Well, it's about the interpersonal side of software engineering.

Comment: @JoelEtherton it has to do with programmers

Comment: @Zarkonnen: So is the telephone, but those types of questions are almost universally closed because it can translate to just about any working environment involving a computer.

Comment: @nischayn22: No it doesn't. It has to do with etiquette and communication. The "programmers" aspect of this question is entirely secondary.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming or programmers considering this problem can exist in any irc channel.

Comment: To clarify: I'm not talking about "how do I use Project X". I'm talking about "how do I hack Project X". It's a question about the culture and etiquette of programmers and OSS projects.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

- Rule #1: Don't ask to ask
- Rule #2: Behave as you would do in a real life conversation
- Rule #3: Be patient. If there is no activity, it usually means that no one has read what you wrote yet. If no one responds, they don't know or didn't notice. You can re-try after a while, or ask if anyone has any clue with regards to your question x minutes ago.

Also, sometimes IRC is not the best way to get help. You could ask if there is a more active forum, like a mailing list, that you can try.

Comment: By "don't ask to ask", do you mean: "don't go 'can I ask you a question?'"?

Comment: @Zarkonnen exactly. "Don't ask to ask. Just ask". Don't ask people "Anybody around?" or let alone highlight others to ask if they are around. It's just easier to drop your question, hang around and wait. Ask again in a few hours or so.

Comment: I've also found that posting updates of your attempts to solve the problem can also be helpful.

Comment: Also, when it's about a specific part of code which is longer than ~5 lines, many IRC users regard it as rude if you don't use services like pastebin.com but paste them directly into the channel

Comment: +1 for the forums and mailing lists. IME they tend to be much more useful than IRC channels for getting technical assistance on a project.

Answer (score 13):

If possible, break your question down to be as simple as possible.  While learning to program I spent a lot of time asking questions in IRC.  Sometimes my code just wouldn't work, and I didn't know why, so I'd put my 200 line program into a paste bin and ask why I was getting an error on line 78. Nobody would answer.

I found that in order to get answers I had isolate the problematic code.  If I couldn't get my example to fit in 20 lines or less, it was hard to get a good answer.  This often required a significant amount of work, but in the process I often solved my own problem before I had to ask in the IRC.

(This advice also applied to good SO questions.)

Answer (score 12):

Check the **timezone** of the main developers, if they're not awake when you IRC them, you'll hardly get any reply.

Some may appear online, but just **left a bot** or **left the client open** to check for some messages when they wake up/come back. If you don't log back on, when they're available, they will have no way of coming back to you, though.

Anyway, for usage directions, **mailing lists** or **issue trackers** work better.

IRC is more useful for developers working on the project: so they can sync and discuss each others' efforts in real time without accidentally starting a flamewar.

(Mistakes and misunderstandings on debatable topics — like *"what to do next?"* — are faster to spot and correct in realtime)

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you're in the right channel. If you're in a developers channel it's obviously not help-desk channel.

If I'm a developer I want to discuss development, not help randomuser #1040 who can't get really well documented feature x working.

Comment: And if you contribute to a community-driven FOSS project, chances are feature X is *very* far from well-documented.

Comment: I guess I should refrain from using hyperboles.

Comment: My point was just that most FOSS project suffer from insufficient manpower and focus on code, no nagging intended.